# C# RichTextBox Find() Bug?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

i don't understand why `position=0` instead `position=-1`

```
RichTextBox.Text = "aaa";
int position = RichTextBox.Find("a", 3, 3, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
```

And `position=-1` if

```
RichTextBox.Text = "aaa";
int position = RichTextBox.Find("aa", 2, 3, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not a bug, but I would say the documentation could be be written as you have to dig in to get the information you need.

After some playing around it is obvious that the rules are as follows:

1. The `start` and `end` values are zero-based indices, so when you put 3 then you are asking it to start at a character that doesn't exist.
2. If you specify both `start` and `end` to be the same value, then the whole text is searched, as specified in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yab8wkhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

Using your examples specifically:

```
RichTextBox.Text = "aaa";
int position = RichTextBox.Find("a", 3, 3, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
```

In zero-based indexing, `3` and `3` are both greater than the actual length of the text, so you are trying to start with a character that doesn't exist. However, because you have used `3` for both `start` and `end` you satisfy the 2nd point above, in that the *whole* text will be search, which is why you get a match at position 0 (the first occurrence).

```
RichTextBox.Text = "aaa";
int position = RichTextBox.Find("aa", 2, 3, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
```

Here you tell it to `start` at the last character, and as you search for 2 characters it cannot match, so you get `-1` as result..

So your results are as expected.

Comment: If the documentation doesn't cover it it __is__ a bug and certainly not as expected. Whether the bug is in the docs or in the behaviour I don't know but wrap around is pretty __crazy__ imo, to put it mildly, so I do call it a bug, __bug__, __BUG__ ;-). The [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yab8wkhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does say, as @Graham notes: _When the start and end parameters are provided the same value the entire control is searched for normal searches_, so it is __not a wrap around__, just weird..

Comment: @TaW: Seems you are right about not being a wrap around, I was sure I proved it was wen testing yesterday but I can't seem to do it now so must have been my mistake. I will update my answer

Comment: ok, thx for your answer. but if start >= RichTextBox.Length, why return 0?

Comment: @GRUNGER: Because in that case `start == end` ( `3 == 3` ), which means search **all** the text (doesn't matter if it's out of bounds, as long as it matches end value)

Comment: Please don't create accounts/ask your friends to like your posts.